# MySQL poor select query performance despite indexes

Tags: mysql

We have two tables, messages and customercontracts defined as follows:

```
create table customercontracts (customer_id varchar(20), 
                                contractnumber varchar(20), 
                                role varchar(4));
alter table customercontracts add index contractnumber (contractnumber);

create table messages (customer_id varchar(20), 
                                contractnumber varchar(20), 
                                message varchar(400));
alter table messages add index contractnumber (contractnumber);
alter table messages add index customer_id (customer_id );
```

And a query like this:

```
select * from messages m, customercontracts c 
 where m.customer_id = '12345' 
   and c.contractnumber = m.contractnumber;
```

There are approximately 4,000 messages rows and 3,000,000 customercontracts rows.  The above query takes approximately 4 seconds to execute despite there being indexes on both customer_id and contractnumber.  'Explain' (in MySQL Workbench) shows a full table scan on customercontracts and a query cost of 628,000.

Questions:

1) Why is there a full table scan on customercontracts when I have indexes on these tables?  What is the cause of the poor performance?

2) How can I rewrite this query to be performant?

Comment: can you pls verify MySQL take the index if you exec:**SELECT * from customercontracts c WHERE c.contractnumber = VALIDNUMBER**

Comment: The PRIMARY KEY is unclear. Please clarify.

Comment: @Strawberry - Apologies, the table definitions are simplified.  The primary key is another column (not included).  contract number and customer_id are separate non-unique keys (using BTREE).  The data is highly unique on both tables.

Comment: @BerndBuffen - Yes, index is used for that statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've finally found the answer to this.  My sample table creation code above did not show the character encoding (a learn for me, don't shortcut sample code!).  As it turns out, the customercontacts table is encoded in utf8 while the messages table is encoded in utf8mb4.

**When columns of different character encoding are joined, indexes cannot be used.**

This answers the 'why is this happening'.  To fix this, we modified the utf8m4 table to downgrade the encoding of the indexed column to utf8 (while keeping the encoding of the rest of the table as utf8mb4).  This has fixed performance for us.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest try composite index on message Table customer_id,contractnumber  and check performance, try to avoid using * in select .

Answer (score -1):

I'd consider adding an INTEGER "id" field as the primary key for customercontracts and then reference through customercontracts_id instead of contractnumber in the messages table. You should see an improvement in performance already.

Alternatively, you can try adding FULLTEXT indexes on both contractnumber columns, but I'd advise for the first option.